# C Program Portability

Tags: c++, c

As we know java is a platform independent language due to JVM it's program can run at any OS.
What about C/C++? could C/C++ exe run at any OS ? Could we have done something about this(Like write once run anywhere)? please clear my doubt about this.
Thanks

Comment: Java is not platform independent, it just brings its platform around. Guess what languages are used to implement the JVM.

Comment: An .exe is a Windows thing, and it's still an .exe, regardless of the originating language. Also, it disgusts me that you use "C/C++", as if they're somehow interchangable languages.

Comment: I think virtual machines like software are implemented using C/C++ like system programming language. now please tell me what lang are used?

Comment: You figured it out! The Sun/Oracle Java Hotspot VM uses C++ to implement the low level functionality, and adapt it to each platform. This means that Java programs are portable to many OSs and platforms, because someone else has first ported some C++ code to run there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - an executable is built for a specific operating system and hardware (CPU) architecture.

If you are carefull not to use any OS specific functions, or any assumptions about word size etc, then c++ source can be recompiled to run anywhere.

Answer (score 4):

C and C++ are traditionally transformed into machine code for a particular CPU type/family, and packed within a format that a particular operating system can start.

There's nothing stopping anyone from making a C or C++ compiler that compiles code to run on a virtual machine in the same sense that java source code is compiled to byte code intended to run on the jvm. Someone

(The usefulness of doing so is another matter though, and e.g. while it's quite far from standard C++, [C++/.CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) compiles a C++ like language to run on .NET)

Comment: "C or C++ compiler that compiles code to run on a virtual machine" - that's basically what LLVM is, and it's possible with some effort to use LLVM bytecode as a portable binary format (obviously with a platform-specific implementation of the portable environment already installed on the target machine, just like Java). I've worked on a product that did this, although unlike Java the code was never run "on the VM" using an interpreter. Imagine if Java *had* to be JIT-compiled, you wouldn't be far off the basic model of what we were doing with both C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Theorically, C programs only need a compiler that produce executable binaries for the target platform. That's why C is used in almost any embedded platform.

Practically, **that require a separate compilation for each target platform**.

C++ is another beast, clearly more complex and rich of features. Depending on the platform, you might or not have a compiler for C++, and if you have, embedded platform often require (for often non-obvious and sometimes critiquables reasons) that some C++ features are deactivated.

So with C++ you still "can" compile for any target platform, because it is a system programming language, like C (meaning that you're "close to the metal" with those languages).

However, there are still some problems you have to solve if you want to target some platforms :

- some platform constructors will not allow you to run binaries on their platforms, only to sue their "secured" virtual-machine based language (whatever it is);
- some platform constructors will provide compilers for their platforms, but with limited features, making them too poor to use for industrial developpement;

So theorically, C and C++ can run anywhere, if you compile for the target and that you use only cross-platform code/library.
In practice, it depends on the context.

Answer (score 1):

Executable programs are platform and OS dependent. There are emulators in some OS that allows to run executables of other platforms (such as wine, dosbox etc. and of course VMWare) but this is an emulation/virtualization only.

Answer (score 1):

Each operating system has it's own executable format, so you have to compile your C(++) program separately for each OS. If you use cross platform libraries, you can easily recompile your program without having to change your code a lot.